# Rails 3.2 - every action in the app is loaded twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, action, webrick, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I take a look into the terminal's output (I use server WEBRick on my localhost), so I see there that every action (no matter what controller) is called twice, always (the second one always 1-2 seconds after the first).

Didn't has anyone the same problem? I tried to search on Google and also a discussions here on SO, but unfortunately I didn't find any useful help...

**EDIT - example:**
when I take a look into the terminal output, so I see there for example:

```
Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-22 01:35:42 +0100
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
...sql queries...
Completed 200 OK in 1690ms (Views: 1451.2ms | ActiveRecord: 28.7ms | Solr: 203.8ms)

Started GET "/articles" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-22 01:35:45 +0100
Processing by ArticlesController#index as */*
...sql queries...
Completed 200 OK in 159ms (Views: 105.8ms | ActiveRecord: 2.8ms | Solr: 49.0ms)
```

This is for every action in controllers of my app. In the browser is everything ok, a visitor don't know nothing about repeated loading the action, but you know... why is there repeated loading of an actions?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example?

Comment: which solr library are you using? sunspot?

Comment: can you share some of the code in your controller?

Comment: from which one? Most of the time, there's just classic SCRUD structure, nothing special... or you mean from ApplicationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is an ajax request it could be caused by the javascript files being included twice. You may have precompiled your assets in development mode. Could you try removing "//= require_tree ." from application.js